# Плод. Об ударении при склонении

Tags: орфоэпия

Как верно: пл**о**да или плод**а**, пл**о**дом или плод**о**м? Лет 30 назад слыхала только первый вариант. Сейчас частенько слышу и в СМИ второй...

Answer (score 1):

[Плод — склонение и ударение в слове](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Как правильно: развитие плОда или плодА?](https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/55643-kak-pravilno-razvitie-ploda-ili-ploda/)

> Словари фиксируют единый порядок: во всех косвенных падежах
>   единственного и множественного числа ударение переходит на окончание:
>   плодА, плодЫ, плодОв и так далее. Других вариантов нормативные
>   справочники не предусматривают.
>
> Правила произношения одинаковы вне зависимости от значения, в котором
>   употребляется слово: будь то ботанический, медико-биологический термин
>   либо «плод» как результат предшествующей деятельности.
>
> Таким образом, правильно: внутриутробное развитие плодА; лопнувшая
>   кожица плодА; трактат о плодЕ и дереве; подавиться плодОм; плодЫ
>   размышлений.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @ Светлана Если ответ решил Вашу проблему, то нужно поставить две галочки, то есть принять его.

Comment: Не две, а одну)

Comment: А где еще одна, третья? Почему участник не может принять ответ, если его проблема решена? Получается, что этот ответ будет гарантированно не принят? Непорядок.

Answer (score 0):

*Для меня было всё тогда новым, Много в сердце теснилось чувств, А теперь даже нежное слово Горьким **плОдом** срывается с уст.*

**Это старая норма ударения,** которую можно встретить в поэзии. Таким образом, ударение в этом слове колебалось, но уже в словаре Аванесова (1987 года) указано, что  норма устарела.